# How to output GRANT permissions in Generate Scripts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been putting my database under source control by running `Tasks > Generate Scripts > Script entire database and all database objects`. Problem is that after granting a user a couple permissions on the db and re-scripting, I noticed there is no difference in the generated script. Is there a way to automatically generate this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools->Options->Sql Server Object Explorer->Scripting->Object Scriptiong Options->Script permissions